# jquery second click no works when add class and remove class

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{

if(jQuery("#init").hasClass("show_box"))
{
jQuery("#init").click(function() {
jQuery("#box").show(1000);
jQuery("#init").removeClass("show_box");
jQuery("#init").addClass("hide_box");
});
}
}); 



jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
if(jQuery("#init").hasClass("hide_box"))
{
alert("ok");
jQuery("#box").hide(1000);
}
});
```

```
<div id="box" style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;display:none";></div>
<span id="init" class="show_box"> Box Action </span>
```

As you can see the jquery script show div with id box when click over Box Action, also add class and remove class, show_box and hide_box, in this moment in the second step when change class and try click for activate second script part and hide box, no works, in this case i try without click for automatic hide when change class for hide box but continue don´t works.

I see inside DOM and show_class change, and i try all kind of things and don´t works in the second step for hide box when click in Box Action

Comment: Your issue (unexplained in the current answers) is that your `.click` handler is only assigned if the #init has the class *on startup*.  Move the `if` inside the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this answer.

don't write on click event 2 times for the same div. just write one on click event and on to this function check with `if else condition`. and add or remove your class.

Also, you can write the same code using `toggleClass`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#init").click(function() {
    if (jQuery("#init").hasClass("show_box")) {
      jQuery("#box").show(1000);
      jQuery("#init").removeClass("show_box");
      jQuery("#init").addClass("hide_box");
    } else if (jQuery("#init").hasClass("hide_box")) {
      alert("ok");
      jQuery("#box").hide(1000);
      jQuery("#init").addClass("show_box");
      jQuery("#init").removeClass("hide_box");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;display:none;">Test</div>
<span id="init" class="show_box"> Box Action </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ideally skip to use multiple `jQuery(document).ready(function()` events.
2. Also `jQuery("#init").click` this should change with new way style of click events. That will works with every elements that created dynamically as well.
3. In **jQuery** you can take advantage of `toggle` & `toggleClass`

   - [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
   - [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#init', function (event) {
        jQuery("#box").toggle(1000);
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('show_box');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('hide_box');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;display:none" ;></div>
<span id="init" class="show_box"> Box Action </span>
```